# Get a single item from an array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, react-context

Im mapping through some context.api data, and displaying that data on a page. this works fine. However, when i want to send a piece of that array.map back to the context for state management, it only chooses the last item. I want it to choose the item you click on.

Code:

```
import { React, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { DataContext } from "../contexts/dataContext";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Example = () => {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [input, setInput] = useState(null);
    const[designation, setDesignation] = useState(null);
    const { data } = useContext(DataContext);
    const { onChange } = useContext(DataContext);
    const { onClick} = useContext(DataContext);

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6 offset-sm-3 offset-md-3 offset-lg-3 offset-xl-3 offset-xxl-3 min-vh-100 text-center p-5 border">
                    {
                        data.map((item) => {
                            return(
                                <div className='row' key={item.id}>
                                    <div className='col-xs-12 placeholder placeholder_image rounded'></div>
                                    <div className='col-xs-12 text-start p-0 pt-2 m-0'>
                                        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                                        <p>
                                            <div className='col-sm-11'>
                                                <a className="no_underline link-dark" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href={item.dataTarget} role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam venenatis sapien...<i className="bi bi-caret-down-fill"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </p>
                                            <div className="collapse" id={item.dataId}>
                                                <div>
                                                    <p>{item.text}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <form>
                                                    <div className='row mt-2 mb-2'>
                                                        <div className='d-grid gap-2 col-8 mx-auto'>
                                                            <div className="form-floating text-start">
                                                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="enterAmount" placeholder='Enter Amount' aria-describedby="enterAmount" onChange={e => {setInput(e.target.value);onChange(e.target.value);}} />
                                                                <label htmlFor="enterAmount">Enter Amount</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className='row mt-2 mb-2'>
                                                        <div className='d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto'>
                                                            <Link to="/checkout"  className="btn btn-lg button-color"  onClick={ onClick(item.title) }>Give <i className="bi bi-arrow-right"></i></Link>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }) 
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Example
```

This is the part that i am using to get the data:

```
<Link to="/checkout"  className="btn btn-lg button-color"  onClick={ onClick(item.title) }>Give <i className="bi bi-arrow-right"></i></Link>
```

the onClick function in my context api looks like this:

```
    const[designation, setDesignation] = useState(null);
```

its just a setState function really.

So why is it that every time its set, its returning the third title in a 3 item array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change onClick event on Link to this.

```
<Link to="/checkout" className="btn btn-lg button-color" onClick={() =>onClick(item.title) }>Give <i className="bi bi-arrow-right"></i></Link> –
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` takes a function, but you’re passing it the value of calling a function.

The function gets called on each iteration, which updates the state each time and ultimately state settles in the last item’s `onClick` call.

Try this:

```
onClick={() => onClick(item.name)}
```